# Getting unexpected crash reports inside a try-catch block

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-mobile, uwp, hockeyapp

I'm using *HockeyApp* to collect crash data for my app, but for some reason it doesn't provide the stack trace.

What I have is something like that:

```
MyNamespace!<BaseAddress>+0x5d1287 
MyNamespace!<BaseAddress>+0x5f18d5 
MyNamespace!<BaseAddress>+0x5f1827 
Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object sender, ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e)
```

so it's kinda hard to find out what's happening.

The exception message is helpful tho, as it says

> Element not found. Cannot find credential in Vault

and there's just one place in which I'm using `PasswordVault`.

The problem here is that I'm using it inside a try/catch block, so I really don't understand why I'm getting this report, and I can't even reproduce it.

This is the full `PasswordVaultService` class, so that you can see exactly what I'm doing.

```
public class PasswordVaultService
{
    private static readonly PasswordVault Vault = new PasswordVault();

    public static string RetrieveSecret(Entry entry)
    {
        try
        {
            var results = Vault.FindAllByResource(entry.Name);
            if (results.Count == 0) return null;
            var result = results[0];
            result.RetrievePassword();
            return result.Password;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void StoreSecret(Entry entry, string secret)
    {
        Vault.Add(new PasswordCredential(entry.Name, entry.Name, secret));
    }

    public static void DeleteSecret(Entry entry)
    {
        var results = Vault.FindAllByResource(entry.Name);
        if (results.Count == 0) return;
        var result = results[0];
        Vault.Remove(result);
    }

}
```

I've been getting this error for some time now, and I don't understand what's going on because the class is quite simple. Before posting I've even searched for *Vault* inside the project and this is the only place where I'm using the `PasswordVault`.

Comment: This [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17955087/21567) might help (the OP had the same issue as you and it was not _really_ answered, so not voting to close this as duplicate).

Comment: OTOH, are you sure that exception is caused by the `RetrieveSecret` method? Couldn't it be raised by `DeleteSecret` (which has no catch block)? Try to get a stacktrace of the original exception (not the one that leads to the "unhandled exception" handler).

Comment: Having it in `DeleteSecret` doesn't seem logical, based on app's flow, but I can't even be sure about this since there's no way to get a stacktrace. My only chance is to push an update with a try/catch on `DeleteSecret` and just hope it worked, since I don't have this issues on my testing devices. Do you know if I can get to some kind of stacktrace from the data returned by HockeyApp?

Comment: Did you upload the PDB file to HockeyApp? Or did you use any third part package? These situations may case the issue on Hockeyapp.

Comment: I feel really dumb now. I use Visual Studio to update builds and I was quite sure it did upload symbols too (the `.appxsym` files). I've uploaded son PDB and it seems it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Well, VS actually uploaded `.appxsym` files but they don't work, only PDB ones are working.

Comment: The .appxsym file should work too, it is a bit strange. But the best way is what you did, upload the pdb file to HockeyApp.

Comment: I've uploaded a new build with both `appxsym` and `pdb`, and now symbols stopped working again. I guess I'll contact their support.

Comment: It usually will take some time to symbolize the crash log. But sometime it maybe a backend issue

Comment: I don't think it's a time-related issue, the logs are coming with a different hash than the symbol's one, and I've uploaded both .appxsym and zipped PDB from store.